# VS Team foundation Service TCP port blocked in build?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to setup a build for my solution in visualstudio.com

One of my projects has a post-build script running that will connect to an external virtual machine where I have a SAP ASE database running.  The purpose is to run database migrations on that server.

The connection is made via an IP through port 5040.
My post build script throws an error saying no connection could be established.

Could it be that VS Team Services is blocking my connection.  And if so, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Does that database can be accessible from internet (not intranet)?

Comment: For example, connect that database at your home?

Comment: Yes, when I build at home I can run the integration tests and migrations on the same IP address and port.

Comment: I made a test, the 5040 port is not blocked on hosted build agent. (http://power-shell.com/tag/powershell-outbound-port/), you can make a test to verify whether it can connect to your server with that code (change ip). On the other hand, share the detail build log here or on the OneDrive.

Comment: Cool thx for the effort, I'm going to check in the afternoon wether I can make it work!

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: Don't get it, I can't make the connection while if I run the tests from my home machine the connection works.  It seems like the build agent is blocking my connection to the database :(

Comment: What's the result after you verifying the port with the PowerShell code (previous comment)? Can you provide the detail build log here?